# C# checking for duplicates

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

guys in my program I am trying to look for duplicates within my listbox by checking whats being entreated in the textbox, although I cannot seem to make it work, duplicates just get added to the array/listbox, any suggestions?

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = txtInitialise.Text;
    bool isDuplicate = false;

    foreach (var name in lstHoldValue.Items)
    {
        if (name.ToString().Equals(text))
        {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isDuplicate)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This number already exists!");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add elements to your Items collection is this way:

```
lstHoldValue.Items.Insert(0, "\t" + numArray[i]);
```

Notice the `\t` at the beginning of the string inserted?.
Now, you should consider this `\t` when you check for string equality

```
string text = "\t" + txtInitialise.Text;
```

(Or just remove the `\t` when you insert)

Comment: Thanks Steve, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the @mybirthname anwser, you can also use linq instead of foreach,  like this: `var isDublicate = !lstHoldValue.Items.All(x=>x.ToString() != test)`

Comment: Probably you mean Any not All. However, as explained the problem is not the ToString() on the ObjectCollection elements but the difference in the strings compared

Comment: @Steve I have a string that should be different from a bunch of other strings, so all strings should be different from my string. `All` makes sense to me